# Creating an error check

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a code for a golf program in one of my classes, using VISUAL BASIC on Visual Studio 2010, and I am trying to create a loop where I enter information and if it is not numeric, not within a certain number limit, and not a blank character it will send back an error message box allowing me to fix the program, but currently if I enter the wrong information, it will just show the message box telling me I am wrong, but proceed to the next step instead of allowing me to re-enter my info.

Here is the code:

```
Do
    sScore = InputBox("Enter Score", "Score Entry ")
    If (IsNumeric(sScore) = True) Then
        If (Not IsNumeric(sScore)) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Score Must Be Numeric", "Validate Score", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            CheckValue = "N"
        End If
        If (Val(sScore) <= 59) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Score Must Be Greater Than 0", "Validate Score", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            CheckValue = "N"
        End If
        If (sScore = "") Then
            MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure You Want To Exit?", "Data Information", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)
            If DialogResult.OK Then
                Exit Sub
            ElseIf DialogResult.Cancel Then
                CheckValue = "N"
            End If
        End If
    End If
    CheckValue = "y"
Loop While CheckValue = "N"
```

Answer (score 0):

There were a number of corrections that needed to be made to enable the functionality your seeking to work. They are commented in the following code:

```
    Try
        Dim inpScore As String = "" ' need to use a string for the return value of the InputBox
        Dim sScore As Integer
        Dim CheckValue As String = "N"

        Do
            ' if non-numeric character or Empty String is inputted 
            ' an exception will be raised
            inpScore = InputBox("Enter Score", "Score Entry ")
            ' Need to test empty string before numeric test
            If (CStr(inpScore) = "") Then
                MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure You Want To Exit?", "Data Information", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)
                If DialogResult.OK Then
                    Exit Sub
                ElseIf DialogResult.Cancel Then
                    CheckValue = "N"
                End If
            End If
            'you do  not need to test for true since function returns a boolean
            If (IsNumeric(inpScore)) Then 
                'Move test and error message to Else statement added below  
                'If (Not IsNumeric(sScore)) Then
                '    MessageBox.Show("Score Must Be Numeric", "Validate Score", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
                '    CheckValue = "N"
                'End If
                sScore = CInt(inpScore)  ' set sScore to inputted value
                If (sScore <= 59) Then ' REMOVE Val( - we know it is numeric
                    MessageBox.Show("Score Must Be Greater Than 0", "Validate Score", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
                    CheckValue = "N"
                Else
                    CheckValue = "Y"
                End If
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Score Must Be Numeric", "Validate Score", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
                CheckValue = "N"
            End If

            'CheckValue = "y" ' remove so that lopp continues
        Loop While CheckValue = "N"
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace your `messagebox.show()` with `Throw New Exception("...")` and then wrap your `DO` loop with an error handler.

This will make you jump out of the loop and still show your message.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it doesn't work should be obvious to you :

```
    Do
        ' ...
        ' ...

        CheckValue = "y" ' <- HERE !
    Loop While CheckValue = "N" ' <- CheckValue is changed to "y" the line before :/
```

---

I think you don't want the user to resume until he enters a valid input or cancel and exit the `InputBox` ?

And you want to know the result of the validation or the cancellation...

So **Step 1** is to create an Enumeration.

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off

Public Enum UserScoreValidation
    ' Add three first states :
    Validated
    Erroneous
    Cancelled
End Enum
```

**Step 2** is to declare the logic with Do/Loop :

```
Public Sub UserInputsScore()
    ' Always declare the type, avoid infering...
    Dim sScore As String ' user input
    Dim enumValidation As UserScoreValidation = UserScoreValidation.Erroneous ' result

    ' Then create the loop...
    Do
        ' ...
        ' ToDo : Placeholder - Remove the following...
        enumValidation = UserScoreValidation.Cancelled
        ' ...
    Loop While enumValidation = UserScoreValidation.Erroneous
End Sub
```

**Step 3** is writing the Loop logic, handling user cancellation :

```
    Do
        sScore = InputBox("Enter Score", "Score Entry ").Trim()
        ' add Trim() to avoid inputs like "  752", but see Trim() note below...

        ' Check results...
        If sScore <> "" Then
            If IsNumeric(sScore) Then
                ' ToDo : Placeholder - Remove the following...
                enumValidation = UserScoreValidation.Cancelled
                ' ...
            Else
                ' Well : non numeric value entered...
                MessageBox.Show("Score Must Be Numeric", "Validate Score")
                ' You don't need the MessageBoxButtons.OK, it's there by default
                enumValidation = UserScoreValidation.Erroneous ' Try again...
            End If
        Else
            ' Either the user entered nothing, either entered spaces, either cancelled..
            ' That's why I don't like InputBox,
            ' You can't know for sure wether user cancelled or entered Whitespaces.
            ' => Assuming the user cancelled
            emumValidation = UserScoreValidation.Cancelled
        End If
    Loop While enumValidation = UserScoreValidation.Erroneous
```

**Step 4** is check the entered numeric value :

```
            If IsNumeric(sScore) Then
                ' I Don't know if you're working with Integers or Floating numbers.
                ' So I assume Integers by default !
                ' Declare an Integer :
                Dim intScore As Integer = -1 ' just to make sure

                ' However, you'll have to move that intScore variable 
                ' at the top of the Method later... (Remember this)

                If Integer.TryParse(sScore, intScore) Then
                    If intScore > 0 Then
                        If intScore <= 59 Then
                            ' CONGRATULATIONS !!!
                            enumValidation = UserScoreValidation.Validated
                        Else
                            MessageBox.Show("Score Must Be equal or below 59", "Validate Score")
                            ' Try again...
                            enumValidation = UserScoreValidation.Erroneous
                        End If
                    Else
                        MessageBox.Show("Score Must Be Greater Than 0", "Validate Score")
                        ' Try again...
                        enumValidation = UserScoreValidation.Erroneous
                    End If
                Else
                    ' Wasn't a valid Integer input ! :(
                    ' However, what about "48.15" or "23." ?
                    ' ^^ that's why I asked, but from now on, 
                    ' those are assumed incorrect entries.
                    MessageBox.Show("Score Must Be entered as Integer", "Validate Score")
                    enumValidation = UserScoreValidation.Erroneous
                End If
            Else
                ' ....
```

**Step 5** the DialogBox to confirm user cancellation :

```
    Do
        ' ...
        ' ...

        If sScore <> "" Then
            ' ...
            ' ...
        Else
            If MessageBox.Show("Do you want to Cancel Score Input ?", "Data Information", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) _
                = DialogResult.OK Then
                ' Bye bye !
                emumValidation = UserScoreValidation.Cancelled
            Else
                ' Try again...
                emumValidation = UserScoreValidation.Erroneous
            End If
        End If
    Loop While enumValidation = UserScoreValidation.Erroneous
```

---

Interlude :

As you can see, there are a lot of `enumValidation = UserScoreValidation.Erroneous`...
Made it that way to show the logic on a first glimpse.

However, note that in the declaration, I've already set `enumValidation` value to  `UserScoreValidation.Erroneous`. So we fix that in step 6 :

**Step 6** :

- Default `enumValidation` value to `UserScoreValidation.Erroneous` **inside** the Do
- and remove all the redundant assignations (and If/Else blocks if possible)..
- handle the validation **after** the Do/While Loop with `enumValidation` and `intScore`

Here's the entire Method

```
Public Sub UserInputsScore()
    Dim sScore As String ' user input
    Dim enumValidation As UserScoreValidation = UserScoreValidation.Erroneous
    Dim intScore As Integer = -1
    ' Note : I've moved intScore declaration here !

    Do
        enumValidation = UserScoreValidation.Erroneous ' Try again by default..
        sScore = InputBox("Enter Score", "Score Entry ").Trim()

        If sScore <> "" Then
            If IsNumeric(sScore) Then
                ' Note : intScore declaration removed !

                If Integer.TryParse(sScore, intScore) Then
                    If intScore > 0 Then
                        If intScore <= 59 Then
                            enumValidation = UserScoreValidation.Validated
                        Else
                            MessageBox.Show("Score Must Be equal or below 59", "Validate Score")
                        End If
                    Else
                        MessageBox.Show("Score Must Be Greater Than 0", "Validate Score")
                    End If
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Score Must Be entered as Integer", "Validate Score")
                End If
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Score Must Be Numeric", "Validate Score")
            End If
        Else
            If MessageBox.Show("Do you want to Cancel Score Input ?", "Data Information", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) _
                = DialogResult.OK Then
                emumValidation = UserScoreValidation.Cancelled
            End If
        End If
    Loop While enumValidation = UserScoreValidation.Erroneous

    ' Now you can resume on using Score Input or User Cancellation :
    If enumValidation = UserScoreValidation.Validated Then
        ' At this point, enumValidation is either "Validated" or "Cancelled"
        ' intScore Value is 0 < intScore <= 59 because of validation above.

        ' so build the next part of your code inside this If block
        ' and using intScore as required.

        ' unless you have something specific to do upon user cancelation,
        ' don't write any Else block and let the code run til the end.
        ' or if you like that much, un-comment the following
    ' Else
        ' Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Why use Enum ?

- Enums can hold different states
- are fast
- are self explanatory
- Enum states are easily changed, replaced, removed, expanded...
- Enums can be easily used in `Select Case` statements

So if you want, you can for example add those values :

- UserScoreValidation.Bad
- UserScoreValidation.Average
- UserScoreValidation.Good
- UserScoreValidation.VeryGood

along with the Erroneous and Cancelled, then use a Select Case to handle different states :

```
Select Case enumValidation
    Case UserScoreValidation.Cancelled:
        Exit Sub
    Case UserScoreValidation.Bad:
        MessageBox.Show("Only " + intScore.ToString() "? :O You're terrible :P ")
    ' ...
```

---

### Note about Trim()

`dotNet Framework 3.5 SP1 and below` remove all common white spaces **including** the ZERO WIDTH SPACE (U+200B) and ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE (U+FEFF). However, since `dotNet Framework 4.0`, the two above *white space* examples **are not removed anymore**, but the three characters MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR (U+180E), NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE (U+202F), and MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE (U+205F) are added and handled by Trim().

[MSDN..](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/t97s7bs3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (Sorry it's in french as MS does an automatic language check, but MS will find your language for you upon requesting the page)

---

**InputBoxes**, **cancel** and **empty inputs**...

If someone knows about a dotNet inbuilt class for a better InputBox, tell me please.

I've come to create my own InputForm Class that is just the same as the default, but with two properties :

- InputForm.Value As String ' using Private p_Value as String = ""
- InputForm.Cancelled As Boolean ' using Private p_Cancelled as Boolean = False

I even added two other properties :

- InputForm.DefaultValue As String ' ReadOnly, set upon setting Value
- InputForm.UserAlteredValue As Boolean ' ReadOnly - True if InputTextBox.Text <> DefaultValue.

If the Framework has such Dialog with such Properties, comment below to notify me. I'm lazy enough to get pissed off each time I had to add this class to a solution :P